# Typeahead autocomplete results not displaying

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead, bloodhound

I'm trying to use the library typeahead.bundle.js (typeahead + bloodhound).

Here is my code :

```
  var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.name);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/%QUERY.json?country=fr&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IlhHVkZmaW8ifQ.hAMX5hSW-QnTeRCMAy9A8Q",
      wildcard: "%QUERY",
      rateLimitWait: 1000,
      filter: function(response) {
        return $.map(response.features, function(city) {
          return {
            name: city.place_name,
            longitude: city.geometry.coordinates[0],
            latitude: city.geometry.coordinates[1]
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  var promise = engine.initialize();

  promise.done(function() { 
    $(".typeahead").typeahead({
      minLength: 2,
      highlight: true,
      hint: false
    }, 
    {
      displayKey: "name",
      source: engine.ttAdapter()
    });
  });
```

Everything seems fine but there is no result displaying.

Can someone help me with that ?

Thanks !

Comment: the request could not be satisfied. that what i get when try to open the url

Comment: Your remote URL is not working

Comment: The URL is working ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments were right, the URL (or actually the token) is invalid. With another token it works well, or sort of works. For cosmetic reasons I changed the response filtering to the more simple

```js
filter: function(response) {
  return response.features.map(function(city) {
    return {
      name: city.place_name,
        longitude: city.geometry.coordinates[0],
        latitude: city.geometry.coordinates[1]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But the main issue is [**this bug**](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1218), that is well known and surprisingly never has been corrected in the github repository (*the twitter.js project seems to be more or less dead*) - it is an issue that only occurs when using bloodhound and remote sources. Here is a [version with the corrections implemented](https://github.com/davidkonrad/stack/blob/master/typeahead.bundle.js) - and now it works - even in a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/m2vLd2u4/**